# Permission denied in terminal

Tags: command-line, uninstall

[image]

I can't uninstall jdownloader. Should I delete the entire folder or do something else. Please help.

Comment: It was probably installed using `sudo` (elevated privileges) and thus you likely need to use elevated privileges to remove it as well.  (I'd check by `ls -la` (`stat` or other) to see permissions are as I assume, but I can't see it from your picture - which should be text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it got installed with elevated privileges.
Best way to get rid of it will be to uninstall with elevated privileges.
Try to run uninstaller with elevated permission.

While executing the command make sure you're in the right folder.
Navigate to `/opt/jd2` then executive the command.

`sudo ./Uninstall\ JDownloader`

It's better to use tab to auto complete while typing such that typos are avoided.

[double tab for suggestions and single tab for autocomplete, if no other file with similar pattern is available.]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out !

In terminal type sudo nautilus.
Type your password and new root file manager will open. 
 Then you can delete any file. 
I deleted whole jd2 folder.

Comment: Running a GUI application like Nautilus [with `sudo` is **not** a good idea in general](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006/480481).